# Acces an array value return to Undefined index

Tags: php

In the `foreach` I want to access the array value and the array looks like this.

```
Array
(
    ['name'] => John Doe
    ['age'] => 25
    ['from'] => Australia
)
```

How do I get the value of `name` `age` and `from`?

With `echo $item['name']` and return `Undefined index: name`.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your foreach loop.

Comment: It's a `$_POST` from `name[], age[], from[]`. I want to preview it back if have an error to the form.

Comment: Ok, but you still need to show the foreach loop for anyone to understand your problem.  As it is now, there is no possible way to figure out what's wrong without guessing.

Comment: If just 3 values from form are in question, why you need loop at all?

Comment: @Anonymous an example http://pastebin.com/Pe6UgjQA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are foreaching over that array you just want ot echo the item:

```
$the_array = array( 'name'=> "John Doe", 'age' => 25, 'from' => 'Oz');
foreach($the_array as $item){
   //the first iterations will echo out $the_array['name'], 
   //second $the_array['age'], etc...
   echo $item;

  //in this loop $item['name'] has no meaning if that's what you're doing....
}
```

Now if it's really an array of arrays  you can do this

```
$the_array = array(array( 'name'=> "John Doe", 'age' => 25, 'from' => 'Oz'));
foreach($the_array as $item){
   foreach($item as $key=>$value){
       echo $key." ".$value;
   }

}
```

If you're not positive the values you want to echo are being set but dont want the inner loop you might:

```
foreach($the_array as $item){
   $name =isset($item['name']) ?$item['name'] : null;
    echo $name;
    $age =isset($item['age']) ?$item['age'] : null;
    echo $age;

    //...etc...


}
```

Comment: With `echo $item` it's return to array to string conversion. http://pastebin.com/Pe6UgjQA

Comment: var_dump $item  What do you get?

Comment: `array(3) { ["'name'"]=> string(8) "john doe" ["'age'"]=> string(2) "25" ["'from'"]=> string(6) "region" }`

Comment: I suspect you're using post array or something, and a value;s not being set, so just check for existance before using @user3337623

Comment: Ahaa.. the value is appearing with duplicate of current amount of my rows. Let me see if something wrong to my session. Thanks Ray for the hints.

Comment: My bad. I have `name[0]["name"]` it should be `name[0][name]`. Problem solved and just use your first example :)